# Codeigniter route with JWT as parameter not working as expected for some users

Tags: codeigniter, routes, jwt

I have a url like the one below with a parameter as JWT token.

> http://localhost/activate/khjdfbhdfgkfgyuyi674.gsdgfhksgdkfjbsdfghgsdfkdsfhsdfjsdufisdf.jhsdfkjsdfhjshdf

I have a function in my controller that handles this route i.e

> function index($token) {
>
> > // $token is the jwt token from the url
>
> }

In my routes configuration i have the route defined as:

> $route['activate/(:any)'] = 'controllername/index/$1'

However some users who access this route end up with $token containing part of the JWT string i.e

> khjdfbhdfgkfgyuyi674

And others end up with $token having the full jwt string i.e

> khjdfbhdfgkfgyuyi674.gsdgfhksgdkfjbsdfghgsdfkdsfhsdfjsdufisdf.jhsdfkjsdfhjshdf

I have failed to reproduce what the problem could be. Looks like the $token from the parameter is only retrieving the string till the period (.) or user is clicking on the link from their email and only the parts till the period (.) are being triggered!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually a problem with some email clients. We were sending the full url link via email so when some users click the first part of the link, it takes part of the url until the first period **(.)** which makes it an incomplete link.
So we decided to add a button to the link in the email to avoid such scenarios from happening again.